# Movie about a teenager discovering time travel

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I remember watching a movie quite a few years ago, where a teenager in high school was trying to find out about possibilities of time travel. I think towards the end he did manage it, but it was really weird. Unfortunately, there's not much I remember.

Some other infos I do remember are:

- He was a really smart kid, stood up to adults in a quite impressive way (I liked that most)
- I'm pretty sure he had psychological problems, and took drugs because of it. Sometimes this resulted in some weird scenes but I don't remember anything specific
- I remember it looked a bit older than modern movies but not too old, so I guess something between the 90s and 2000ish

I'd appreciate your help a lot !

Comment: I was very distracted while watching it back then. Recently I remembered it again and I'd like to watch it with full attention, because I really liked it.

Comment: Teenager with mental issues makes me think of Donnie Darko, but I dont remember enough to be certain.

Comment: Do you recall a freaky looking bunny? That would sort of give it away.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As Radhil said in a comment, this does sound like [Donnie Darko](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0246578/).

> a teenager in high school was trying to find out about possibilities of time travel. I think towards the end he did manage it, but it was really weird.

More or less:

> He (inexplicably, in the film) manages to send something to the past and change things.

A book called "The philosophy of time travel" was also involved, as well as some conversations about it with one of his teachers.

The other points:

> He was a really smart kid, stood up to adults in a quite impressive way (I liked that most)

He stood up to a local celebrity who was full of excrement and one of his teachers who followed said celebrity's "teachings" like a gospel. He even did so on an open microphone in front of the entire school.

> I'm pretty sure he had psychological problems, and took drugs because of it. Sometimes this resulted in some weird scenes but I don't remember anything specific

He was taking drugs for schizophrenia (if I remember correctly) and there were some scenes where he was seeing strange things.

> It's unclear whether he saw these things because of the illness or another reason.

Finally,

> I remember it looked a bit older than modern movies but not too old, so I guess something between the 90s and 2000ish

The film was released in 2001 but was set in the 1980s.

Comment: That sounds like the movie I'm looking for. To be sure I will watch a trailer when I get home, after confirmation I'll mark your answer as accepted :)  thanks for the help and useful answer, I'd vote it up but I'm brand new on the site and don't have the necessary reputation yet

Comment: Don't worry about it, glad to help (if I did) :)

Comment: It is Donnie Darko ! I know what I'm doing this evening hehe

Answer (score 22):

In addition to Donnie Darko, this also sounds slightly like [*The Butterfly Effect*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Butterfly_Effect), starring Ashton Kutcher from 2004 (but had a lower budget, grittier feel that made it look/feel older).

I don't recall Evan specifically taking drugs/medications, but he was in therapy and dealing with doctors.

He was, however, intelligent and tried standing up to adults who were doing horrible things to him and his friends.

He is actually able to use time travel a few times through the movie, using it to try to prevent bad things from happening at all. The time travel scenes were marked with very heavy visual effects.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe Fetching Cody from 2005.

Here is a synopsis of that film:

> "Drug dealer Art (Jay Baruchel) is panic-stricken when his prostitute girlfriend, Cody (Sarah Lind), overdoses and falls into a coma. Help comes in the unlikely form of a homeless man's grungy armchair. In addition to being a comfortable recliner, it's also a time machine. To rescue Cody from her ill-fated future, Art uses the chair to go back in time and change the past. But along the way Art discovers that saving Cody may mean sabotaging his relationship with her."

Comment: Hi :) you should put some link or say why you think this might be the answer ;) and if you want an easy badge simply take the [tour]

Comment: Bunk, less is more.  This is EXACTLY the right answer to the question.  Regardless of how many points Cody has.

Comment: i agree with @zipzit - here is a synopsis of that film: "Drug dealer Art (Jay Baruchel) is panic-stricken when his prostitute girlfriend, Cody (Sarah Lind), overdoses and falls into a coma. Help comes in the unlikely form of a homeless man's grungy armchair. In addition to being a comfortable recliner, it's also a time machine. To rescue Cody from her ill-fated future, Art uses the chair to go back in time and change the past. But along the way Art discovers that saving Cody may mean sabotaging his relationship with her."

Comment: Right or wrong, adding what about the film matches up with the description, or even just providing a description of the film in the answer would make this much more useful and would garner more upvotes.

Comment: Rocket is correct. You might think it is correct but an good answer should make their *p*oint, give ***e*vidence**, and *e*xplain. PEE.